# Can you control you PC with a laptop flawlessly over wifi?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, software-rec

I have a high end desktop computer, 32GB DDR3, GTX 780Ti, I5 a 3.5Ghz and 20TB of storage.
However I don't like to be condined in my room, being with my roomates will be much more pleasant.

If I buy a low end laptop, I don't know, something around 600€, something that has a great battery life and a shitty graphic card.

Can I find a software that can stream the desktop screen and allow control as if I was on the real thing over **WIFI (300MBp/s)**.

Meaning being able to play video without tearing or color loss du to compression (I'm thinking about teamviewer here)
I will mainly do coding with Eclipse and some 3D works with blender or 3Ds max.
But I don't want to have to switch back to enjoy some cat video over youtube.

Thanks.

Comment: why paying 600€, you can just buy a small monitor along with a wireless keyboard and mouse, and connect the monitor with a wireless HDMI, and just adjust the settings, make it the primary screen and the other one is the extended screen. then you can use it around your apartment, and you have save a lot of money! this is just an idea, try to think out of the box, an avoid using the network sharing even if you have a high speed network, it won't give you the same experience as you're working directly from your desktop !

Comment: this indeed looks like a very good idea! however I doubt it could reach every part of the house. I'm going to make a deep search about this.

Answer (score 5):

If the Laptop and Desktop are part of the same network and use OS that support RDP, you can use RDP (Remote Desktop).

You can't use RDP to connect to computers running Windows 7 Starter, Windows 7 Home Basic, or Windows 7 Home Premium , but you can use RDP to initiate a connection from any edition of Windows 7.
This is for the native RDP tool (mstsc.exe)

[Here](http://lifehacker.com/whats-the-best-remote-desktop-tool-1506973784) are a few of the best RDP Tools

Comment: You could also VNC which works regardless of Windows version... RDP is much better in a Windows environment, though

Comment: And it doesn't have to be part of the same network.

Comment: Doubt RDP is much use for video streaming http://superuser.com/questions/570179/why-remote-desktop-rdp-isnt-fast-enough-for-watching-videos-on-a-remote-pc